# How to refer to another key in the same appsettings.json

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I wonder if there is a way to refer to another key in the same appsettings.json in ASP.NET/Core project.

In the following example I wonder if it's possible to refer to the "DBName" key in the "DefaultConnection" because they share the same value:

{
  "DBName": "MyDbName",

"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "server=localhost;port=3306;user=username;database="MyDbName";"
  }
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This is not possible. Config values are just strings. They aren't parsed for things like variables. I suppose you could sort of work around this with something like:

```
{
    "DBName": "MyDbName",
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "server=localhost;port=3306;user=username;database={0}"
    }
}
```

Then:

```
var connectionString = string.Format(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), Configuration["DbName"]);
```

Essentially, you leave a `string.Format` placeholder in your actual connection string value and then replace this manually via your `DbName` config value.

However, that's pretty brittle. Honestly, you're not doing this right in the first place. Configuration is override-able by environment. So, if you need to do something like switch out the DB name, you're likely in a different environment and should therefore being overriding the connection string value via an environment variable or environment-specific JSON.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, please do you have an example/tutorial of how "should therefore being overriding the connection string value via an environment variable or environment-specific JSON"?